# Use Magento UI Form Component Outside Of Form? (Product Category Selector)

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, phtml

I need to use the Product Category Chooser:

[image]

But not inside of a usual UI Component form. Is this possible? Basically I want to call it from a .phtml file for a custom admin page I'm building.

Comment: Have you checked this. https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/267021/59677

Comment: Thanks yes that was what I needed :) I also had to add this to my JavaScript since I was calling the x-magento-init via ajax:  
$('#topbanner-category-select').trigger('contentUpdated');
                        and 
$('#topbanner-category-select').applyBindings();