# How to add category filter in using $fieldset->addField without component?

Tags: category, filter, magento2.4.5, category-tree, addfield

I want to know about the way of adding category chooser using $fieldset->addField.
What should I do?
I try as follows.
[Magento 2 Add category chooser without UI component](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/266944/magento-2-add-category-chooser-without-ui-component)

but error is occurred as follow.

```
[2023-06-29T06:49:31.971904+00:00] main.CRITICAL: InvalidArgumentException: Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Chooser doesn't extend \Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement in F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory.php:88
Stack trace:
#0 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\AbstractForm.php(157): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Factory->create('Uedakanamono\\Ba...', Array)
#1 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset.php(214): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\AbstractForm->addField('category_ids', 'Uedakanamono\\Ba...', Array, false)
#2 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(58): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset->addField('category_ids', 'Uedakanamono\\Ba...', Array)
#3 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(138): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor->___callParent('addField', Array)
#4 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\Interception\Interceptor.php(153): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor->Magento\Framework\Interception\{closure}('category_ids', 'Uedakanamono\\Ba...', Array)
#5 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor.php(131): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor->___callPlugins('addField', Array, Array)
#6 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner.php(212): Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\Fieldset\Interceptor->addField('category_ids', 'Uedakanamono\\Ba...', Array)
#7 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form.php(156): Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner->_prepareForm()
#8 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1094): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Form->_beforeToHtml()
#9 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#10 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#11 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor.php(446): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#12 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs.php(492): Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor->toHtml()
#13 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\view\adminhtml\templates\widget\tabs.phtml(73): Magento\Backend\Block\Widget\Tabs->getTabContent(Object(Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tab\Banner\Interceptor))
#14 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php.php(71): include('F:\\xampp\\htdocs...')
#15 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(263): Magento\Framework\View\TemplateEngine\Php->render(Object(Uedakanamono\BannerSlider\Block\Adminhtml\Banner\Edit\Tabs), 'F:/xampp/htdocs...', Array)
#16 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template.php(293): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->fetchView('F:/xampp/htdocs...')
#17 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\app\code\Magento\Backend\Block\Template.php(141): Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template->_toHtml()
#18 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1095): Magento\Backend\Block\Template->_toHtml()
#19 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(1099): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->Magento\Framework\View\Element\{closure}()
#20 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock.php(660): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->_loadCache()
#21 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(578): Magento\Framework\View\Element\AbstractBlock->toHtml()
#22 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(555): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderBlock('Uedakanamono_ba...')
#23 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('Uedakanamono_ba...')
#24 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('Uedakanamono_ba...')
#25 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('Uedakanamono_ba...', false)
#26 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('Uedakanamono_ba...', false)
#27 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('left', false)
#28 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#29 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('left')
#30 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('left', false)
#31 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('left', false)
#32 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('side.col', false)
#33 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#34 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('side.col')
#35 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('side.col', false)
#36 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('side.col', false)
#37 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.main.conta...', false)
#38 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#39 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.main.conta...')
#40 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.main.conta...', false)
#41 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.main.conta...', false)
#42 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.content', false)
#43 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#44 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.content')
#45 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.content', false)
#46 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.content', false)
#47 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('page.wrapper', false)
#48 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#49 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('page.wrapper')
#50 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#51 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('page.wrapper', false)
#52 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('backend.page', false)
#53 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#54 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('backend.page')
#55 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('backend.page', false)
#56 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(606): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('backend.page', false)
#57 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(557): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->_renderContainer('root', false)
#58 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(149): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#59 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(510): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderNonCachedElement('root')
#60 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->renderElement('root', true)
#61 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Layout.php(975): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->renderElement('root')
#62 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor.php(347): Magento\Framework\View\Layout->getOutput()
#63 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page.php(260): Magento\Framework\View\Layout\Interceptor->getOutput()
#64 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout.php(171): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Page->render(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#65 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor.php(140): Magento\Framework\View\Result\Layout->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#66 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Http.php(120): Magento\Backend\Model\View\Result\Page\Interceptor->renderResult(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Response\Http\Interceptor))
#67 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\generated\code\Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor.php(23): Magento\Framework\App\Http->launch()
#68 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\lib\internal\Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap.php(264): Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor->launch()
#69 F:\xampp\htdocs\magento2\pub\index.php(30): Magento\Framework\App\Bootstrap->run(Object(Magento\Framework\App\Http\Interceptor))
#70 {main} [] []
```

How to fix it?

Comment: The error message is pretty clear. you need to extend `\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement` to be able to use the class inside a form. Implement the required methods and you are done

Comment: I had tried it, but error is occured continuously.
\Magento\Framework\Data\Form\Element\AbstractElement Who can answer? Please post a example code in detail. Thank you for your time.